# How to find the terminal in Lubuntu?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu

Where can I find the terminal in Lubuntu? I thought the CTRL+T option works as it does in Ubuntu too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will open terminal on all Ubuntu variations & versions, except Kubuntu (by default).

Or GUI way, according to the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

**Menu > System Tools > LXTerminal**

Answer (score 9):

Ctrl-Alt-T is the default short cut - for both Lubuntu and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

ALT-F2 and type lxterminal

But in Lubuntu one is not bound to use  lxterminal which is somewhat limited (less settings) compared to Gnome Terminal and Xfce Terminal, and may install those in synaptic and use them instead.

To set shortcuts in Lubuntu edit the file /home/user/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml

Answer (score 0):

right click on mouse or trackpad: it will show up the Terminal option. Or go to the left down corner and go on "acessories" and Terminal...

Answer (score 0):

#### Lubuntu >= 18.10

**lxqt** is used, `ALT-F2` and enter `qterminal`

#### Lubuntu <= 18.04

**lxde** is used, type `lxterminal`.